# Need help with IVP for Heat Equation

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve the heat equation on a torus and am running into a problem... Mathematica keeps running, but never finishes/ends. Even after leaving it running overnight, I still got nada.

Thoughts?

Here is my code(I also tried "DSolveValue"):

```
ClearAll

eqs = {D[[u][t, x, y], {t, 1}] == 
   D[[u][t, x, y], {x, 2}] + D[[u][t, x, y], {y, 2}]}; 
torusBC = {[u][t, 0, y] == [u][t, 2*Pi, y], [u][t, x, 0] == [u][t, x, 2*Pi]};
iv = {[u][0, x, y] == 
    DiracDelta[0, x - 0, y - 0] + DiracDelta[0, x - Pi/3, y - 0] + 
     DiracDelta[0, x - 2*Pi/3, y - 0] + 
     DiracDelta[0, x - Pi/6, y - Pi/2] + 
     DiracDelta[0, x - 3*Pi/6, y - Pi/2]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs, torusBC, iv}, [u][t, x, y], {t, x, y}] //
  FullSimplify
Plot3D[sol[x, y, t], {0, 2*Pi}, {0, 2*Pi}]
```

---

So, I've gone through and made the corrections... And reverted back to DSolveValue because of the dirac deltas. This is the code now:

```
eqs = D[u[t, x, y], {t, 1}] == D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}]; 
torusBC = {u[t, 0, y] == u[t, 2 Pi, y], u[t, x, 0] == u[t, x, 2 Pi]};
iv = {u[0, x, y] == 
    DiracDelta[x - (Pi/4), y] + DiracDelta[x - (2 Pi/3), y] + 
     DiracDelta[x - (4 Pi/3), y - (Pi/4)] + 
     DiracDelta[x - (Pi/3), y - (3 Pi/4)] + 
     DiracDelta[x - (5 Pi/3), y - (3 Pi/4)]};

sol = DSolveValue[{eqs, torusBC, iv}, u[t, x, y], {t, x, y}]

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[sol, {x, 0, (2 Pi)}, {y, 0, (2 Pi)}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, h}], {t, 0.00001, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Now it's giving me a whole host of errors, but it at least looks like it's trying to compute something.

Thoughts?

For w/e it's worth... I'm doing this so I can spit out a contour graph at some random time, to turn into a .stl to 3D print for a demonstration. My use of 3D plot is really just to help me determine what time to choose.

Comment: Your code is full of simple mistakes. 1. `ClearAll` at the beginning doesn't do anything, please check the document of `ClearAll` carefully. 2. `[u]` is clearly wrong, actually when I try executing your code, _Mathematica_ immediately gives `Syntax::sntxb` warning and stop, I won't why your code runs overnight. 3. The `{t, x, y}` is wrong, `NDSolveValue` is a numeric solver, you need to specify a domain for it. Please read the document of `NDSolveValue` carefully. 4. `DiracDelta` won't work in numeric solver like `NDSolveValue`, you need to approximate it with smooth function...

Comment: ...5. Boundary conditions are missing. In a word, please calm down, learn the basics of _Mathematica_ first. When you encounter problem, check the document by pressing **F1**. Coding blindly won't help.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for pointing those out to me, I just corrected them and updated my question to reflect the corrections. 

Having said that, I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Now the equation looks suspicious, you mentioned you're solving on a torus, then usually we need laplacian in polar coordinates, but you're using that in Cartesian; the b.c. is also suspicious. Can you show us the problem in traditional math notation?

Comment: I'm using those BCs so that u(t,x,y) is 2 Pi periodic that way I can bound the graph (x,y) [0, 2 Pi]x[0, 2 Pi] and that argue what I eventually print is this sort of "lumpy" torus in its identification space.

Comment: I'm doing this because, I'm a second-year grad student(taking my quals in the fall) trying to pitch a dissertation topic to a few of my professors. But unfortunately, I don't have the mathematical background or vernacular yet to convince them(small dept with limited course offerings). But I won't develop either unless I convince them. So, to meet them halfway, I thought a physical demonstration of my thought might do the trick.

Comment: My experience with Mathematica is to start simple. Instead of a torus, use a disk or rod. Duplicate a textbook example. Then start adding complexity. If you can't get these to work, then you have something to address. Go even simpler, perhaps the one-dimensional cooling of a sphere. Eventually you find out if the problem is understanding of physics or understanding of Mathematica. There are always epiphanies and breakthroughs in the latter, even after years of use.

Comment: Your model involves terms like `DiracDelta[x - (2 Pi/3), y]`, which lies on the boundary. Then what convension are you choosing for `HeavisideTheta[0]`?

Comment: @xzczd I SEE WHAT YOU MEAN! So, it sounds like it might be easier to calculate the eigenvalue solutions and put those through a series assuming periodic BCs.

Comment: @PaulCommentary yea... that was my next step if I keep struggling with this. Solve THIS problem by hand, and poke around Mathematica to get the "lay of the land" so I better understand it before I "need" to use it again.

Comment: I'd say finding a numeric solution with `NDSolve` is the better choice. You just need to approximate `DiracDelta` with a smooth function. Though improved these days, `DSolve` is still not that good at PDE solving.